# Ionic Serve Failing With Typescript Error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a basic Ionic application I'm developing with Firebase and Firestore as Auth and DB.  I've run into this same problem on my Windows and MacOS machines, and my friend is having the same issue on his MacOS machine.  Additionally, the issue is present via our own code base and when we clone a git repo with similar setup (Ionic + Firebase).

After adding the Firebase information in the environments.ts files and adding the firebase packages, we run Ionic Serve and always get the same TS1005 error.

We've rolled back Typescript to 3.4.3.  We originally had 3.6.4 but found references to a dependancy requiring a version below 3.5.0.

We've updated Node to version 12 and have tried NPM Install and updates to try to ensure we have the right packages.

Below is our Packages.json:

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^7.2.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "8.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

We expect the Ionic Serve command to load the app in the browser.  We get the below error in terminal instead:

```
[ng] ERROR in src/environments/environment.prod.ts:3:3 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
[ng] 3   firebaseConfig: {
[ng]     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] src/environments/environment.prod.ts:12:4 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
[ng] 12   };
[ng]       ~
[ng] src/environments/environment.ts:7:3 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
[ng] 7   firebaseConfig: {
[ng]     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] src/environments/environment.ts:16:4 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
[ng] 16   };
[ng]       ~
[ng]
```

Comment: Can you show environment.ts?

Comment: I solved this, there was some errors in the script provided by Firebase in the Environments files.